# Unable to parse XML with Xerces-C++

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, xerces

I'm trying to parse a XML document using Xerces-C++. I just would like to be able to search for a element by its id. I have written the following code but it doesn't work.
...

```
try {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
    }
    catch(XMLException& e) {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode( e.getMessage() );
        cout << "XML toolkit initialization error: " << message << endl;
        XMLString::release( &message );
    }

    XMLCh tempStr[100];
    XMLString::transcode("LS", tempStr, 99);
    DOMImplementation *impl = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(tempStr);
    DOMLSParser* parser = ((DOMImplementationLS*)impl)->createLSParser(DOMImplementationLS::MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, 0);

    char *filename = "C:\\odx1.xml";


    xercesc::DOMDocument *doc = 0;

    try {
        doc = parser->parseURI(filename);
        DOMElement *element = doc->getElementById(XMLString::transcode("test"));
        if(element != NULL) cout << "element found";
        cout << "DONE";
    }
    catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
        cout << "Exception message is: \n"
                << message << "\n";
        XMLString::release(&message);
        return;
    }
    catch (const DOMException& toCatch) {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.msg);
        cout << "Exception message is: \n"
                << message << "\n";
        XMLString::release(&message);
        return;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "Unexpected Exception \n" ;
        return ;
    }

    parser->release();
    XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
}
...
```

The XML is:

```
<ODX MODEL-VERSION="2.2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="odx.xsd">
  <DIAG-LAYER-CONTAINER ID="test">
    test done
  </DIAG-LAYER-CONTAINER>
</ODX>
```

I expect it to print "element found" but the program terminates correctly without printing "element found".

Anyway...in the XSD file associated to the XML document the element I'm searching for has `<xsd:attribute name="ID" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>`
So I expect the element to be returned by getElementById.

Comment: Can you also add your XML ?

Comment: if you want some help, "it doesn't work" is not enough information. What does your code produces and what did you expect it to produce ?

Comment: How is the XSD file associated to the XML document? Maybe you are using a `schemaLocation` inside the XML file? Alternatively you could also specify the schema inside your software (see http://codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/03/15/validating-external-schemas-xerces-cxx/ )

Comment: It is specified like this:
<ODX MODEL-VERSION="2.2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="odx.xsd">

Comment: You could try adding:  DOMConfiguration* conf (parser->getDomConfig ()); conf->setParameter(XMLUni::fgXercesSchema, true);

Comment: Have you made sure that the parser can find and is actually loading your schema?

Comment: The XSD is in the same directory of the XML file. Is this sufficient?

Comment: @EricSjolund...your comment gave me the solution...if you write it as a answer I can give you the +100 for the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
XMLCh tempStr[100];
    XMLString::transcode("LS", tempStr, 99);
    DOMImplementation *impl = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(tempStr);
    DOMLSParser* parser = ((DOMImplementationLS*)impl)->createLSParser(DOMImplementationLS::MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, 0);
    DOMConfiguration* conf = parser->getDomConfig ();
    conf->setParameter(XMLUni::fgXercesSchema, true);
    char *filename = "C:\\odx1.xml";


    xercesc::DOMDocument *doc = 0;

    try {
        doc = parser->parseURI(filename);
        DOMElement *element = doc->getElementById(XMLString::transcode("test"));
        if(element != NULL) cout << "element found";
        cout << "DONE";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at [this](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-2/classDOMDocument.html#fb3e89ba1247d689c4570f40003ea5db)

> Returns the DOMElement whose ID is given by elementId. If no such
>   element exists, returns null. Behavior is not defined if more than one
>   element  has this ID. The DOM implementation must have information
>   that says which attributes are of type ID. Attributes with the name
>   "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined. Implementations that do not
>   know whether attributes are of type ID or not are expected to return
>   null.

Maybe you can get the element by other means ? as tag name ?

Comment: Do you know how to define attributes as id?

Comment: @salvo you might want using DTD for this end, please see this http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/dtd_attribute_types_id.cfm.

Comment: Anyway...in the XSD file associated to the XML document the element I'm searching for has

<xsd:attribute name="ID" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>

So I expect the element to be returned by getElementById